# Ajax não enviando requisição

Tags: jquery, ajax

Não consigo enxergar aonde está o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me acusa esse erro

```
$("#btnSalvarArquivo").on('click', function () {

    var EspecieArquivo = document.querySelector('input[name="rdEspecieArquivo"]:checked').value;
    var tipoArquivo = 0;

    var erros = 0;
    $("div").find('*').each(function () {
        var classe = $(this).attr("class");
        if (classe !== undefined) {
            var numItems = $('.has-error').length;
            if (numItems > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                if (EspecieArquivo === "0") {
                    var TipoArquivo = document.querySelector('input[name="rdTipoArquivo"]:checked').value;
                    console.log(TipoArquivo);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'ProtocoloLatam/Inserir',
                        dataType: 'JSON',

                        data: {

                            EspecieArquivo: EspecieArquivo,
                            TipoArquivo: TipoArquivo,
                            numeroProtocolo: $("#txtNumeroProtocolo").val(),
                            dataProtocolo: $("#txtDataProtocolo").val(),
                            prazoConclusao: $("#txtPrazoConclusao").val(),
                            colaborador: $("#txtNomeColaborador").val(),
                            bp: $("#txtBP").val(),
                            emailColaborador: $("#txtEmailColaborador").val(),
                            tipo: $("#cmbTipo").val(),
                            classificacao: $("#cmbClassificacao").val(),
                            torre: $("#cmbTorre").val(),
                            processo: $("#cmbProcesso").val(),
                            subprocesso: $("#cmbSubprocesso").val(),
                            cidadeOrigem: $("#cmbCidadeOrigem").val(),
                            quantidade: $("#txtQuantidade").val(),
                            ftp: $("#txtFTP").val(),
                            caixaNBox: $("#txtCaixaNBox").val()

                        }, success: function (data) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                toastr.success("Cadastrado com sucesso.");
                            }, 2000);


                        }
                    });
                } else if (EspecieArquivo === "1") {
                    var TipoArquivo = document.querySelector('input[name="rdTipoArquivo"]:checked').value;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'ProtocoloLatam/Inserir',
                        dataType: 'JSON',

                        data: {
                            EspecieArquivo: EspecieArquivo,
                            TipoArquivo: TipoArquivo,
                            numeroProtocolo: $("#txtNumeroProtocolo").val(),
                            dataProtocolo: $("#txtDataProtocolo").val(),
                            prazoConclusao: $("#txtPrazoConclusao").val(),
                            colaborador: $("#txtNomeColaborador").val(),
                            bp: $("#txtBP").val(),
                            emailColaborador: $("#txtEmailColaborador").val(),
                            tipo: $("#cmbTipoUnitario").val(),
                            classificacao: $("#cmbClassificacaoUnitario").val(),
                            torre: $("#cmbTorreUnitario").val(),
                            processo: $("#cmbProcessoUnitario").val(),
                            subprocesso: $("#cmbSubprocessoUnitario").val(),
                            cidadeOrigem: $("#cmbCidadeOrigemUnitario").val(),
                            ftp: $("#txtFTP").val(),
                            caixaNBox: $("#txtCaixaNBox").val()
                        }, success: function (data) {

                            $("#minhaModal").modal('hide');

                        }
                    }).done(function () {
                        toastr.success("Cadastrado com sucesso.");
                        setTimeout(4000);
                        window.location.reload();
                    });
                }


                return false;

            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente seu código está quebrando antes mesmo de executar a requisição Ajax. Parecce que não está conseguindo encontrar a propriedade value do "`var EspecieArquivo = document.querySelector('input[name="rdEspecieArquivo"]:checked').value;`
"

Tente criar a sua variável sem a propriedade value e faça um console.log para ver como está o elemento.

```
var EspecieArquivo = document.querySelector('input[name="rdEspecieArquivo"]:checked');
console.log(EspecieArquivo);
```

Comment: Sim, era isso mesmo, tirei esse cara desse lugar e voltou a funcionar, valeu

Comment: Outra coisa cara, vc está misturando a sintaxe do jQuery com Vannila, isto não é muito indicado!

Comment: depois vai ser padronizado rs, estou em fase de testes

Answer (score 1):

Provavelment o retorno de alguma chamada à `querySelector()` é `null`.

Tente debugar o valor dessas variáveis:

```
var a = document.querySelector('input[name="rdEspecieArquivo"]:checked');
var b = document.querySelector('input[name="rdTipoArquivo"]:checked');
```

Teste no console mesmo.

Comment: O problema era ele mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: Sem problemas, depois que eu vi que já haviam respondido! :)

Comment: Aquele value do checked estava me jogando pro buraco, custei enxergar isso

Answer (score 1):

esse é todo o código que tu ta usando? 
caso sim, No trecho:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rdEspecieArquivo"]:checked').value;
```

eu não encontrei em nenhuma otra parte do teu código que tenha esse **input** com name **rdEspecieArquivo**.

O mesmo para o **rdTipoArquivo**. Então, como o intepretador n acha, acaba dando null, e aí tu tenta extrair value de null...

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo, ele estava na posição errada